# Task :react-native-autogrow-textinput:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED issue

Tags: react-native, debugging, npm, error-handling

I'm trying to run my project in windows machine which is running perfectly in my mac device. But I'm facing these issue while running this project. Here is the detailed error screen shot. Anybody please review it and help me to find a solution for this. I have tried some commands like `./gradlew clean` `npm audit fix --force` but none of these didn't worked for me.

Script file in my package.json is

`"scripts": { "android": "react-native run-android", "android-release": "react-native run-android --variant=release", "ios": "react-native run-ios", "start": "react-scripts start", "test": "jest", "lint": "eslint ."}`

The error message is,

```
    > Task :react-native-autogrow-textinput:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
BUILD FAILED in 25s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't set up android development environment in your windows machine.

Follow the instruction mentioned here to [setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

It's already mentioned in above that **"If you already have a JDK on your system, we recommend JDK11. You may encounter problems using higher JDK versions."**

Comment: My development environment has been set up correctly and tried running other projects and created a new sample project. But everything is working fine. This error is occurred only while running a specific project.

Comment: Can you check the java version used in both machines

Comment: In my windows machine, java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing). But in my mac machine I couldn't find java jdk version. Even though in mac my project is working fine. Only the problem with windows machine.

Comment: downgrade to Java 8 or Java 11, then you are good to go